# mysql insert into creates 2 records in table row

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Ok .. I'm stuck. I tried several codes from topics here, but still not working for me so I need a little help please.

I want to log if a user is logged in for the first time and want to update that same record if the user returns. The update part works, but when my function is executed the first time, it insert a total blank record and a record with all the data provided by variables. The last_login column is NULL for the first vist and is nicely updated with the last login.

But what I can't figure out is why the first login creates these extra records.

Here is the function code I created:

```
function log_users($userId, $username, $achternaam, $district, $gemeente, $ipaddress)
{
    global $connection;

    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM logfile_sap WHERE user_id = '{$userId}'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {

        $sql = "UPDATE logfile_sap SET last_login = NOW() WHERE user_id = '{$userId}'";
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    }
    else
    {     

        $sql = "INSERT INTO logfile_sap
                (user_id, username, achternaam, district, gemeente, ipaddress, first_login)
                VALUES
                ('{$userId}', '{$username}', '{$achternaam}', '{$district}', '{$gemeente}', '{$ipaddress}', NOW())";
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    }
}
```

So as you can see I am checking if the user already exists in the logfile_sap table and if it does NOT exist I want to insert the user (which works but with an extra row) and if the user already exists the record is updated.

This is the code I use on top of the page that needs to check and adds the data in the table:

```
<?php log_users($userId, $username, $achternaam, $district, $gemeente, $ipaddress); ?>
```

I hope some has a brighter idea than me ;-)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Problem SOLVED. I had an epiphany !!!

I called my function OUTSIDE my if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) statement.

After I've put it INSIDE the if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) statement, there was only one record inserted into the table !!

Comment: I think your functions seems fine.

Comment: FYI you can combine the two queries using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: The `INSERT` query sets `first_login`, but not `last_login`.

Comment: I suspect you're calling the function twice, and one of them has empty arguments. There's no way this function can create two rows by itself.

Comment: @Barmar: that is updated (which it should) and not inserted. That works perfectly. Your "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" sounds interesting. Will give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED. I had an epiphany !!!

I called my function OUTSIDE my `if(isset($_SESSION['id']))` statement.

After I've put it INSIDE the `if(isset($_SESSION['id']))` statement, there was only one record inserted into the table !!

Comment: You should edit the question to show the original problem. The answer doesn't make sense without it.